# How to trigger DrillThrough with Report Viewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using ReportViewer with my WPF application.

I'm trying to trigger a function within my c# code and the button will be on the ReportViewer.

I'm wondering how do I trigger the DrillThrough?

```
void DemoDrillThroughEventHandler(object sender, DrillthroughEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Drillthrough worked");
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this._reportViewer.Drillthrough += new DrillthroughEventHandler(DemoDrillThroughEventHandler);
        this._reportViewer.Reset();

        ....
        this._reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this._reportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a method what rises event (`OnSomething`, to example, in winforms there is `Button.PerformClick`). Otherwise you can put code from event handler in separate function and call it directly.

Simplest solution to call it

```
DemoDrillThroughEventHandler(this._reportViewer, new DrillthroughEventArgs());
```

or even (depends on what is going on inside)

```
DemoDrillThroughEventHandler(null, null);
```

Comment: Hi @Sinatr where would I put that? I only have an expression screen, I don't see where I can put the code. http://i.snag.gy/10oPQ.jpg

Comment: I have no idea what is the screen you have linked.